# How the statement if is evaluated in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

How is a condition inside the `if` statement evaluated to `true` or `false` in JavaScript?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/665056/502381

Comment: @Juhana: This explains the equality comparison algorithm, not how `if` statements are evaluated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the OP is asking, he's just not using the correct terms. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the result of the condition expression is, it is [converted to a Boolean by `ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5):

> 1. Let *`exprRef`* be the result of evaluating *`Expression`*.
> 2. If `ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef))` is **`true`**, then
>      Return the result of evaluating the first *`Statement`*.
> 3. Else,
>      Return the result of evaluating the second *`Statement`*.

For each data type or value, [the conversion rules to a Boolean are clearly defined](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2). So, for example, `undefined` and `null` are both converted to `false`.

Comment: +1 BTW, there's now a canonical HTML version of the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/ Not as pretty as es5.github.com, but doesn't have the big weird green guy, either. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: :D The green guy can be really disturbing ;)

Answer (score 3):

`undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, and `false` are all "falsey" values. Everything else is a "truthy" value.

If you test a "falsey" value, the condition is false. E.g.:

```
var a = 0;

if (a) {
    // Doesn't happen
}
else {
    // Does happen
}
```

If you test a "truthy" value, the condition is true:

```
var a = 1;

if (a) {
    // Does happen
}
else {
    // Doesn't happen
}
```